# System.hashCode broken on Id properties of SObjects?

Tags: apex, hashcode

Just wasted some time trying to get a big business logic unit test to pass and tracked it down to this.

Here is a failing test demonstrating just the problem of using [System.hashCode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_system_system_hashcode) for [Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm) values:

```
@isTest
private class HashCodeTest {

    @isTest
    static void test() {

        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Acme');
        insert a;
        Id aId = a.Id;

        Set<Integer> s1 = new Set<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> s2 = new Set<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> s3 = new Set<Integer>();

        Integer n = 8;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            s1.add(System.hashCode(String.valueOf(a.Id)));
            s2.add(System.hashCode(aId));
            s3.add(System.hashCode(a.Id));
            System.assert(a.Id == a.Id);
        }

        System.assertEquals(1, s1.size());
        System.assertEquals(1, s2.size());

        // This fails: same (equals) object but n different hashCodes not 1
        System.assertEquals(1, s3.size());
    }
}
```

The last assertion demonstrates the problem: referencing the `Id` field of an object returns an `Id` object that has a different `hashCode` every time (n in the set instead of 1 in the set) even though the `Id` values are equal. So the normal `equals`/`hashCode` [contract](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html) is violated.

Please comment/answer if I'm missing something here - to me this looks like an Apex bug but I may be deluding myself.

**PS**

Probably related to but not the same as [Id object and String object representing the same entity ID are equal but don't have the same .hashCode()](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YQ0AAM).

Comment: You should probably get a PM to look into this.

Comment: For what it is worth, I ran the body of the test method as anonymous apex against API v34.0. It completed with no assertion issues. This was against na5, which is currently reporting the release as Summer '15 Patch 13.1.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Meaning it is broken in that patch too right?

Comment: @KeithC Maybe I misinterpreted your assertions. Are you expecting the last assertion to fail or pass to indicate a problem with the `hashcode` method? You're saying that every time you call `System.hashCode(a.Id)` you are getting a different integer back?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I've reversed the pass/fail so it would pass if hashCode behaved as I expect (1 value in the set) but presently fails (8 values in the set). So if you run the code as posted now it will fail.

Comment: @KeithC Yes, I see the issue now. Something like `System.assertEquals(System.hashCode(a.Id), System.hashCode(a.Id));` shows the same issue. Something odd happens when assigning Id's in the debug log. The `VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT` events show a string message with **no** heap address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The workaround is shown in the question: convert the Id to a String first to get a consistent `hashCode`:

```
Account a = ...;
Integer hashCode = System.hashCode(String.valueOf(a.Id))
```

**PS** I've created a case with Salesforce reporting the bug.

Comment: Just got this from Salesforce support: R&D confirmed this issue will be resolved along with the known issue: "all hashcodes should be the same provided the criteria is met". I tried to find that known issue but could't.

Answer (score 3):

## Update: Fixed!

I just tested this in a Spring '21 sandbox and it is fixed! The Known Issue still says *In Review* but I assume that's because the release isn't in production instances yet.

Note that this is a versioned behavior change beginning with version `51.0`. It's called out in the release notes [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_nc.htm&type=5&release=230#System_namespace_sd:%7E:text=VERSIONED%20BEHAVIOR%20CHANGE%3A%20From%20version%2051.0%20onwards%2C%20the%20hashCode(),same%20hashCode%20for%20identical%20Id%20values.).

---

This is still broken. I worked with support to get the scenario added to the known issue referenced in the original question (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YQ0AAM).

Note that I reproduced the issue a bit differently, using the following code:

```
Id id1 = UserInfo.getUserId();
Id id2 = UserInfo.getUserId();
// passes, the ids are equal
System.assert(id1.equals(id2));
// fails, the hashcodes are not equal
System.assertEquals(System.hashCode(id1), System.hashCode(id2));
```